# form.getResponses().length returns inconsistent responses.

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

If one has a Google form with the following script attached to the spreadsheet:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("INSERT ID");
SpreadsheetApp.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss);//Make it active. 
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Form responses 1');
var form = FormApp.openById('INSERT ID');

function testSubmission() {
var numberOfResponses = form.getResponses().length;
var cell = sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn());
cell.setValue(numberOfResponses);
}
```

I would expect the form.getResponses().length to always count incrementally upwards. However, on occasion, it will skip an increment by one. For example, you might see 1,2,3,3,5,6 etc.

This can happen no matter how far apart the response. See my test responses here: [image]

Has anyone else experienced this? Why does this happen? I suspect it may be a bug, but am looking for some confirmation before reporting.

Comment: Tried and tested the scenario. Surprisingly it is giving me similar values with repeated values in the response length. Not able to find the reason though.

Comment: Sounds like a propagation delay where there is a gap between when the response is added to the sheet and when getResponses() returns it.  One thing that isn't clear is when are you executing that function. Is it in a trigger? Or manually after you see a submission added?

Comment: The trigger is 'On form submit', so as the form is submitted, I would expect that the form.getResponses().length increases in a consistent way.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't reproduce with your code, but it did completely miss posting a count once.

Consider:

- Using `.getActiveSpreadsheet()` instead of `openById()` when the ss you are referencing is holding the script.
- Not using `.setActiveSpreadsheet(ss)`, don't see a need for
- Having the Form hold the script instead of a ss. The onSubmit trigger may be more reliable there although it's not likely related to this issue. `.getActiveForm()` can then be used.
- Separating the responses var from its length. `var responses = form.getResponses();` `var len = responses.length;`
- Taking the Form and ss out of global scope
- Using [LockService](https://gist.github.com/erickoledadevrel/91d3795949e158ab9830)

Comment: You have to include multiple submissions before the issue becomes prevalent, unfortunately, it's not consistent at all. :/